# How do I use PHP sessions and implement basic ACLs?

Tags: php, session-variables, access-control

I have been Googling session variables.  As I understand it, I can use them to capture such things as username and other data.

I would like to be able to use the data in order to store the username of the last person to change the record of a particular field. Additionally, I would like to be able to limit what a particular user sees on the site. For instance, if a user generates a work order I would like that user to be limited to seeing only the work orders he/she creates and no one else's.

I'm very new at all of this and I don't have a enough understanding to even write some code you might correct for me.  How can I send the data stored in the session variable as $_GET or $_POST? If I have it in that format I can use it in the query (I think).

1. I have a table called "work_orders" with a field called "updated_by". I would like to be able to store the ID of the last person who updated the record.
2. I would also like to add privileges to the work orders so that users can only view records created by particular users.

This is a project I undertook in my first year web design class. In the class are some students who think it is funny to see how much damage they can do to the work of others. This is the reason I would like to be able to limit them to accessing only the work orders they generate.

Comment: It would really help in answering your question if you gave a specific problem and perhaps some code you've tried while looking for a solution. The question as you have written is very broad and difficult to answer.

Comment: Sorry. I will edit the question to be more specific. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing your questions here.

Firstly, where is your database? If it were - for instance - MySQl, then you need to add an extra column to the work order table (and others. Personally, I like to add timestamp column to, for auditing porpoises) .

I prefer POST over GET because 1) it can hold more data and 2) it's not so easy for the user to tamper with.

So, if you have a form with an input field declared

```
<form>
```

Name:

(see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

You can access `$_POST['user_name']` e.g
 `$sql = 'INSERT INTO work_order_table (user_name, ... <other column names>) VALUES($_POST['user_name'], .. <other values>)`

I woudl recommend you to get a good book (cheap enough second had) or online tutorial and work your way through.

Pleas let me know if I missed anything or if anything is not clear. Good luck!

---

Since you are concerend about school kids screwing with your datbase

1) google for how to make MySql more secure
2) hint this will involve [prepared staments](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
3) use POST, rather than get, so that you have urls like `http://192.1.68.1.1/application` rather than `http://192.1.68.1.1/application?user=smith` which tempt users to muck around with the URl "just to see what happens" (probably more of a danger than SQL injection at school level, but ... you never know
4) hit the libbrary for soemthign like O'Reilly's PHP & MySql for Dummies in 24 hours for complete idiot beginners - or find a god online tutorial
5) "I would like to be able to limit that particular user to viewing only the work orders they generated" READ up on WHERE in SQL SELECT
6) change the MySql root password - or even add anew user with root-like access then delete root
7) make sure that no student has acess to the server, lest they look at the PHP and see your MySql user & password

Comment: Thanks for the response. The database is MySQL with a table, work_orders. I have a field in that table to store the username of the last person to update the data. The field name is userlogin . Also I would like to be able to limit that particular user to viewing only the work orders they generated. This is for a school project where I am enrolled in first year web design. It will be used to store class room data. There are some students there who would delight in mucking up the work of others, so I'm trying to put as many limits as I can. I will edit the question to make it more clear. thanks

Comment: +1 for feedback. Oops, since this is for school, no one will give you code. In fact, questions tend to get closed if you ask too general a homework question. What people like here is for you to show your work so far and ask a specific questin about a specific problem. However ... I have updated my answer a little

Comment: 1) Google for how to make MySQl secure (I won't do it for you ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I have been googleing for days. It isn't exactly a homework question. I took upon myself to make a site for the school to make a data base driven application that would store these records. Formerly it was all paper based. I've gone beyond what my teachers can help me with, the class is based on using Dreamweaver and using the wizards. I want to learn more than how to use a wizard. I want to understand what is going on. I'm not asking for code, but to be pointed in the right direction. I read so much on the web but lack the foundation to understand it, so I come here to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by reading or watching a video tutorial that will help you better understand how and when to use session variables. The data that you store in the session won't stick around forever, so you will need to store most information in a database.

Here is what most people do: Once the user signs into the application, you put their user id into the session. This way, you know who they are. The server uses a cookie to make this bit of magic happen and when the user closes their browser, the server will forget who they are and the session data will be lost. So, in this example, the session is just keeping track of who the user is.

To store information about who last edited a field, you will probably want to use a database to store that information. There is no use in storing that information in a session variable.